# Why different requests return same geolocation with google geolocation api

Tags: geolocation, google-geolocation

I send two requests to google geolocation api:
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=[mykey]

1st request:

> {"Carrier": "T-Mobile","CellTowers":[{"Age":0,"CellId":"39627456","LocationAreaCode":"40495","MobileCountryCode":"310","MobileNetworkCode":"260","SignalStrength":-95,"timingAdvance":0}],"HomeMobileCountryCode":"310","HomeMobileNetworkCode":"260","RadioType":"gsm"}

2nd request:

> {"Carrier":"T-Mobile","CellTowers":[{"Age":0,"CellId":"4912","LocationAreaCode":"20516","MobileCountryCode":"460","MobileNetworkCode":"00","SignalStrength":-60,"timingAdvance":55555}],"HomeMobileCountryCode":"460","HomeMobileNetworkCode":"00","RadioType":"gsm"}

The weird thing is both of them return same geolocation

> {  "location": {   "lat": 39.90403,   "lng": 116.407526  }, 
>   "accuracy": 18000.0 }

Anyone know why this happen?
Is a bug of google geolocation database?
how can I got (lots of real) testing data?

Comment: I also not understand that the version of this api, v1? many of other api are go to v3, why geolocation ap is still at v1?

Comment: The api will return the same result for all the requests...

Comment: how do you send the request? by curl or http request?

Comment: I'm having this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the quotes "" around the numbers, I don't have an API key for this one, but it might be it.

For example your first request:

> {"Carrier":
>   "T-Mobile","CellTowers":[{"Age":0,"CellId":39627456,"LocationAreaCode":40495,"MobileCountryCode":310,"MobileNetworkCode":260,"SignalStrength":-95,"timingAdvance":0}],"HomeMobileCountryCode":310,"HomeMobileNetworkCode":260,"RadioType":"gsm"}