# Why different POST requests using python and curl return same geolocation with google api

Tags: python, json, google-maps, curl

I have the same question as in the link below.  That question remains unanswered:
[Why different requests return same geolocation with google geolocation api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484392/why-different-requests-return-same-geolocation-with-google-geolocation-api)

I have the same question, Why do I get the same google data response on every request?  The data I get is always the same.

If I send the curl POST request to Google, I get the same response no matter the value in the JSON key value.

If I send POST request using Python 2.7 using requests I always to the same response no mater the value I set in my variable use for the URL POST request.

Any ideals, what key values would be needed, so I can pull the desired data.  For example I want to parse the "locationAreaCode" for various area codes, and I want the request to return the "lat" and "lng" for each lookup.

Using the terminal in MAC OS:

```
curl -d @your_filename.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=[use your Google API key]
```

Note: "your_filename.json" is the literal name for the .json file.
This .json file is currently configured below(I have tried various key values):

```
[
  "cellTowers",
  [
  "locationAreaCode",
  415
  ]
]
```

When I use python 2.7 with the request syntax, I will get a "response 200" and I will get the exact same data returned.

I always get the same response:
Confirming Status Code is:  200

This is the POST url sent to Google 
[link - had to remove since new user to stackoverflow]
Data Returned on the POST request is:

```
{
 "location": {
  "lat": 25.7459338,
  "lng": -80.30449569999999
 },
 "accuracy": 37571.0
}
```

Output from python 2.7:

```
python API_json2-6.py
[link - had to remove since new user to stackoverflow]
Status Code is:  200
Confirming Status Code is:  200
This is the POST url sent to Google 
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=[your google api KEY]&locationAreaCode=415
Data Returned on the POST request is: 

    {
     "location": {
      "lat": 25.7459338,
      "lng": -80.30449569999999
     },
     "accuracy": 37571.0
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah for some reason I am having this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#content), the basic architecture for a server-side geocoding application is the following:

- A server based application sends an address to the server's geocoding script.
- The script checks the cache to see if the address has recently been geocoded.
- If it has, the script returns that geocode to the original application.
- If it has not, the script sends a geocoding request to Google. Once it has a result, it caches it, and then returns the geocode to the original application.
- Sometime later, the geocode is used to display data on a Google Map.

Please note also on the given quota considerations for the things to be avoided when running client-side geocode requests at periodic intervals and on caching considerations wherein The Google Maps API allows you to cache geocodes (i.e. store them on your server for a limited period). Caching can be useful if you have to repeatedly look up the same address.

Comment: You're talking about geocoding. This is different from the OP's question which talks about geolocation. They are two separate API endpoints.